# Trying to get process filename from window name

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, process

Edit: I figure this isn't the best way to go about it. So instead when I gather the window title I add their names to the tag of the control I use to store them. So when the user selects the process earlier in the application it will save the tag into a variable for later use.

I am trying to get a processes filename/path from the window title that I have. I figure I am probably going to have to get the processes name from the title then get the filepath from there. I am pretty lost though. Here is what I have so far for retrieving the process from the window.

```
    Dim ProcessRunning() As Process

        Dim MyProcess As Process

        ProcessRunning = Process.GetProcesses
        For i = 0 To ProcessRunning.Length - 1
            MyProcess = ProcessRunning(i)
            If MyProcess.MainWindowTitle = WindowTitle.Text Then
                MessageBox.Show(MyProcess.ProcessName)
            End If

            Next
```

Comment: What if two unrelated processes create windows with the same title?

Comment: Possible I geuss but not probable since the window titles are from games and they almost always use their game name in the title.